# How can I make this binary operator work with CGFloats?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm making a game at the moment. I haven't run into many errors like this, but I know it's really easy to fix.

Heres the code:

```
func randInRange(range: Range<Int>) -> Int {
    return  Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.endIndex - range.startIndex))) + range.startIndex }
```

Here is the constant I'm trying to work with:

```
let random = randInRange(self.frame.size.width * 0.3...self.frame.size.width * 0.6)
```

The **error** comes out as this: Binary operator '...' be applied to 2 CGFloat operands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method randInRange is expecting a range of Integers, so you need to convert the result of your expression from CGFloat to Integer.

```
let random = randInRange(Int(self.frame.size.width * 0.3)...Int(self.frame.size.width * 0.6))
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude! :)

Comment: @JoshSchlabach If this question has helped you to solve the original problem, please mark it as accepted. This is how StackOverflow works and when you accept the answer it means that problem is solved by given solution (and tell the others that this is the right solution).